# Align a text frame when creating a ppt from access vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to align a text frame when creating a ppt from access. Alignment control is available from excel vba but I'm struggling to find this in access.

Here is an example of the creation of a textbox in powerpoint from access vba. I have control of the font size and such but I cannot locate the alignment for the textbox.

```
' Program data
Dim tb_ProgramData As Shape
Set tb_ProgramData = pptCurrentSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=68.399, Top:=51.12, Width:=187.2, Height:=18.72)
tb_ProgramData.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = rs.Fields(27) + " Program: " + rs.Fields(29)
tb_ProgramData.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 9
tb_ProgramData.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
```

The only thing close is a paragraph alignment but it has no effect...

```
tb_Title.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
```

Any help would be appreciated... regards,

Comment: `Shape` may be ambiguous. Try `Dim tb_ProgramData As Powerpoint.Shape` or similar (I don't know the ppt object model).

Comment: Disambiguation of "alignment": Are you trying to center the shape on the slide? If so, vertically or horizontally, or both?

Comment: I'm looking to control the alignment of the text within the textbox shape. For instance I would like to place a textbox shape onto the right side of the slide then align the text in this textbox to the right of the textbox shape for formatting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Good grief.. I found it under the text effects.

```
tb_SystemClass.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentRight
```

and if you wish to select the textbox from the list of shapes then...

```
pptCurrentSlide.Shapes.Range("tb_SystemClass").TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentRight
```